# Asking about tips on code and other methods how you would do it

Tags: support, questions, rules

Is it okay to ask about better ways to write a script/program and post a 300 line shell program?

Comment: You will have to add a lot of explanation, e.g. which parts you consider most questionable and why. If there is more than one aspect to discuss in your program then you run the risk of being told to ask a more focused question and to reduce the code to the relevant part.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the info

Comment: It most certainly will be off-topic on stackoverflow - you may take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ it might be a better fit.

Comment: If *how you would do it* requires a whiteboard (aka architecture, high-level design, capabilities, etc), consider for that part software engineering.se. It doesn't seem you can simple dump that script in a question box and get answers that are useful for future visitors.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203077/bash-script-to-setup-new-debian-installs